# attach google drive file automatically to send mail

Tags: php, email, google-drive-api, sendmail, attachment

I'm in php, and I need to attach a google drive file automatically, to send it through mail.
Which I have right now is:

1. HTML Table like this:

   Tipo

   ```
           <span class="js-sorter-desc glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
           <span class="js-sorter-asc glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
       </th>
       <th data-field="Etiquetas" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Etiquetas

           <span class="js-sorter-desc glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
           <span class="js-sorter-asc glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
       </th>
       <th data-field="Fecha" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Fecha

           <span class="js-sorter-desc glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
           <span class="js-sorter-asc glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
       </th>
       <th data-field="Nombre" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Nombre

           <span class="js-sorter-desc glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
           <span class="js-sorter-asc glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
       </th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="fila_filtros filtros_buscador_drive">
       <th>
           <input class="js-filter  form-control" type="text" value="">
           </th>
           <th>
               <input class="js-filter  form-control" type="text" value="">
               </th>
               <th>
                   <input class="js-filter  form-control" type="text" value="">
                   </th>
                   <th>
                       <input class="js-filter  form-control" type="text" value="">
                       </th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   <tr class="boton_enlace_directo" data-destino="newmail" data-id="Redactar E-Mail" data-vars="var_fichero_gdrive=1kth1GhrmMEBK2cAMyiy_4Dw1qlJFNdXVuXajJ6nMTQgvar_fichero_gdriveManual KumbiaPHP 1.0 beta2var_fichero_gdriveapplication/vnd.google-apps.documentvar_fichero_gdrivevar_fichero_gdrive">
                       <td>application/vnd.google-apps.document</td>
                       <td></td>
                       <td>05/03/2015</td>
                       <td>Manual KumbiaPHP 1.0 beta2</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr class="boton_enlace_directo" data-destino="newmail" data-id="Redactar E-Mail" data-vars="var_fichero_gdrive=1PwXa6f32BJuAC_m5X5wB9lPzoXAg__uKdUx-1efY4owvar_fichero_gdrive1392970712_Informe 2.docxvar_fichero_gdriveapplication/vnd.google-apps.documentvar_fichero_gdrivevar_fichero_gdrive">
                       <td>application/vnd.google-apps.document</td>
                       <td></td>
                       <td>15/09/2014</td>
                       <td>1392970712_Informe 2.docx</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr class="boton_enlace_directo" data-destino="newmail" data-id="Redactar E-Mail" data-vars="var_fichero_gdrive=0B4X2ktyVTp3mVmtjR2JTSTVreE0var_fichero_gdrive148b14b859c2fa4a.htmlvar_fichero_gdrivetext/htmlvar_fichero_gdrivehttps://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B4X2ktyVTp3mVmtjR2JTSTVreE0&amp;export=downloadvar_fichero_gdrive16">
                       <td>text/html</td>
                       <td></td>
                       <td>26/09/2014</td>
                       <td>148b14b859c2fa4a.html</td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
           </table>
   ```

In each  tag I add some data attributes in order to pick up them

2. I'm picking up these parameters well, and loading the template of new mail form well. But I don't know how attach a google drive file automatically. I'm trying this:

---

```
if( isset($_REQUEST['var_fichero_gdrive']) && $_REQUEST['var_fichero_gdrive']!="" ){
    $metadata_fichero = explode("var_fichero_gdrive",$_REQUEST['var_fichero_gdrive']);  //guardamos el array en una nueva variable
    $fichero_gdrive = array(
        "name" => $metadata_fichero[1],
        "type" => $metadata_fichero[2],
        "tmp_name" => $metadata_fichero[3],
        "error" => 0,
        "size"  => $metadata_fichero[4]
    );
    $_FILES['file'] = $fichero_gdrive;
    unset($fichero_gdrive,$metadata_fichero);
    $gest->uploadAttachment();
}
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally obtained it by the "downloadUrl" param which google drive api returns. With it I access to the google drive file content, and thanks to the strin g $_REQUEST['var_fichero_gdrive']) ( which I mentioned above ), I can obtain the donwloadUrl param, that is, "var_fichero_gdrive" is a string like this:

```
var_fichero_gdrive=IDvar_fichero_gdriveNAMEvar_fichero_gdriveDOWNLOAD_URL
```

I call to php with ajax, and in php I pick up this variable, and I use explode in order to obtain these google drive file data ( you can add what you want ):

```
$metadata_fichero = explode("var_fichero_gdrive",$_REQUEST['var_fichero_gdrive'];
```

If there isn't downloadUrl param, I do something like this:

```
if ( !isset($downloadUrl) || trim($downloadUrl) == "" ) {
        $file["downloadUrl"] = $file->exportLinks['application/pdf'];
    }
```

With line above I create a new downloadUrl, thanks to exportLinks.

And finally, I use file_put_contents to insert the content downloaded of the file, to the file in the tmp directory:

```
$lDrive       = new CGoogleDrive(TOKEN);
$response_body = $lDrive->getDownloadFile( ID_GOOGLE_DRIVE_FILE );
file_put_contents( $dest, $response_body );
```

Hope that it helps. You'll neeed to adapt the code above to your needs.
Regards,